# How can I identify which wire should hook to my headlight switch in my Mazda Protoge (91)?

Tags: headlight, wiring

The headlight switch in my dash is not connected to anything (I noticed this after the headlights quit working!), so I took the dash panel off in an attempt to find the plug. The only plug I could find is the one that was hooked to the dashlight-dimmer, it's visible in the bottom right of the photo. Where would I look to find out which wires might be headlight related? They're obviously colour coded, is there a legend somewhere?

[image]

*Added the thumbnail for now.  Can update later - Bob*

Comment: Photo link:
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-mfcK_gW11P8/T9pUmzs-w3I/AAAAAAAAGVQ/Zih6PkBTcGg/s144/DSCN4839.JPG

Comment: I think you had linked a thumbnail. If you have larger photo, give proper link, and we could edit it into your post.

Comment: If we ever get a bigger picture, we can add it in place of the thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find a Japanese car that doesn't have the connectors strategically arranged to where it's not possible to connect the wrong things together. There should be a matching connector somewhere.

The only exception to that are diagnostic connectors used at the factory and dealerships to test components. Those will not have their counterparts anywhere in the car.

So unless someone has previously hacked up that wiring harness, it should just hook back up, since your lights were working before.